# Replace percentage of True items in Boolean Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that maybe looks like:

```py
matches = np.array([True, True, False, False, False])
```

I need to replace the `True` values with `True` or `False` depending on a probability. For example if the probability is 0.5 one or the other will get replaced with `False`. Actually each element will have the probability applied to it.

So I have numpy where. But I cant quite figure out how to do it:

Where `value == True` replace with random value.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the True values. What do you mean by "I need to replace the True values with True or False depending on a probability". You say you want a random value, but there's several probability distributions, is it a normal distribution? Or uniform? etc.

Comment: OK thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: oops! so for each true value: if random value out of 100 is above a certain value replace with False. So if threshold is at 75%................... if random value >= 75 then change boolean. Uniform I suppose for each item.

Comment: Or.............. replace a percentage of the trues with False

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear. What I am still not sure about is what kind of probability distribution do you wanna use. Should all numbers between 0 and 100 have the same likelihood of occurring (uniform distribution) or should they follow some other distribution?

Comment: They should have the same likelihood. Uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a uniform probability distribution

```
import numpy as np
matches = np.array([True, True, False, False, False])
# Here you create an array with the same length as the number of True values in matches
random_values = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(sum(matches)))

# Setting the threshold and checking which random values are lower. 
# If they are higher or equal it returns False, if they are lower it returns True
threshold = 75
random_values_outcome = random_values < threshold 

# Substituting the True entries in matches with corresponding entries from
# random_values_outcome
matches[matches == True] = random_values_outcome
```

Comment: OK that is super marvellous. Thanks for your help. The last line is the key, just replacing a subset of the array with the same size array. Have a great day!

Comment: Apparantly I am too much of a numpty to cast a vote!!

Comment: No problem! What I did in the last line is called "Boolean array indexing", basically you can set a condition, such as matches == True, and by using that as the array's index you will get all elements matching that condition. You can look into this at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import random

matches = np.array([True, True, False, False, False])
for position, value in np.ndenumerate(matches):
    if value == True:
        matches[position] = random.choice([True, False])

print(matches)
```